# Selecting which dataset to download based on a query string value

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a project where I would like to select which dataset to import based on the url through which the shiny app is accessed. I'm having difficulties doing so however. Currently I have the something that looks like this:

```
query <- getQueryString()
queryText <- paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse=", ")
region <- paste(sub(".*?region=(.*?)", "\\1", queryText))

if(region == "a"){"download data1"}
else{"download data2"}
```

However, this does not seem to work. I have managed to show the value of the query string in a verbatimTextoutput, but only if it was created in a reactive environment. I would like to perform this action outside of the server environment however, as a new dataset is generated every time the API I'm using and I don't want it to do so unnecessarily and my UI relies on the data from this set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything you run outside of the server environment will only be run once on starting the app, are you sure you don't want to run this in the server?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, The dataset is regenerated elsewhere every time it is called, so I would like to minimise the number of times this happens and so have it run only once when the app is accessed

Comment: Allthough I just realised that I do need the code to rerun every time someone reloads the page... Thanks for your response, I'm going to try to move it to inside the server environment

Comment: Cool. Just FYI, if you want something to run once every time someone reloads the page, that will have to be in the server. When I said "anything run outside the server environment will be run once on starting the app", I meant when the app is first deployed (and never again). See for example https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html.

Comment: Managed to get it working, thanks a lot! I've been stuck on this for days now.